# Комментарии Django. Как и где взять?

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте! Появилась задача, нужно добавить комментарии к сайту используя Django. Но, как я понял, после 1.5 (вроде) убрали встроенную функцию `django.comments`. Нашел на `GitHub` репозиторий, вроде можно вручную подключить. Но когда я установил через `pip` и добавил в `config` файл, в `INSTALLED_APPS` я получаю следующее:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.comments'`

Как это можно исправить, или есть альтернативы этому? или придется все же писать самостоятельно модель для комментариев? Спасибо!

Comment: Функционал комментариев укладывает в 15 строк кода, если писать самому. Если с фильтрацией мата и с защитой от флуда, то вытянет аж на 70!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev у Вас есть пример этих 15 строчек? Мне бы очень помогло :)

Comment: Комментарии это обычная форма с записью полученных данных в БД, и соответственно выводом данных обратно туда где хотите эти комментарии отображать,  это грубо говоря пару строк кода тем более с джанговским орм, зачем для такого искать встроеные модули ? Записали комментарий в базу, вывели обратно в тот шаблон где он должен отображаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно надо было:
добавить 'django.contrib.comments' к INSTALLED_APPS.
Запустить

```
manage.py migrate
```

И добавить в urls.py вашего проекта:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    ...
)
```

А вообще - неплохая практика - использовать встраиваемый сервис **[Discus](https://sheensay.ru/disqus)**. Раз и навсегда :-)